# Mac OS X not detecting 2 displayport monitors as separate displays

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors

I have two ThinkVision p27q monitors connected to a MacBook Pro via a Thinkpad Thunderbolt dock. OS X is picking them up as if they were a single monitor and displaying the same thing on both.

The arrangement screen in Mac Preferences > Display doesn't show them as separate monitors.

How can I get OS X to see them as separate displays?

Comment: It may not be possible if the dock acts as a splitter.

Comment: The monitor has HDMI, DP, mDP, DP-out .  Try daisy-chaining them (DP to the first, DP-out to the second).  You could also try an HDMI adapter->HDMI cable to the second monitor, which might interpret the second monitor as separate now.

Comment: On review, it looks like Apple STILL doesn't support DisplayPort daisy chaining, but you can still try an HDMI cable. Some MacBooks have a standalone HDMI output also.

Comment: I tried both the daisy-chaining and the HDMI with no luck unfortunately :( The monitors work absolutely fine connected to a lenovo thinkpad running ubuntu so I know it's the mac. That's annoying that Apple don't support daisy chaining